# Does this leak in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, memory-leaks, closures

I have an aspx page that makes an Ajax request (using jquery) to a web service to return some data.

my onerror handler is something like this (not exactly but this is the idea):

```
onerror: function(status,xhr, whatever) {
  var objectResult = eval('('+xhr.Status+')');
  alert(objectResult.Message);
}
```

Question:

Will this create a potential memory leak due to the eval expression being assigned to my local var?

Thank you.

Comment: as a side note: http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=13979

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will definitely *not* result in a memory leak.

Your `objectResult` variable will be destroyed at the end of the function (since it's a *local* variable).

The actual object in memory that `objectResult` was *referencing* is then free to be garbage collected (since the only variable referencing it was destroyed). It probably won't be garbage collected right away, though.

Answer (score 1):

No, this should not create a memory leak.  The `objectResult` variable should be cleaned up as it leaves scope when your handler finishes.